# Unable to import from module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have the following structure:

```
repo_folder
    |--> main.py
    |-->_init_.py
    |--> scripts (folder)
            |---> utils.py
```

I want to import all the classes/functions in utils.py to main.py to do that I tried the following things:

1) `from scripts.utils import *`  got an error that scripts module wasn't recognized.

2) moved main under scripts and edited the line `from .utils import *`

I use python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 when trying (1) no errors marks shown over the IDE (Pycharm)

Thank you for helping!

Comment: How do you execute ˋmain.pyˋ? Are you aware of ˋ__main__.pyˋ?

Comment: facing problem in pycharm or executing through terminal?

Comment: Try adding an `__init__.py` file to your `scripts` folder as well.  Then use `from scripts import utils`.  Failing that, check your `sys.path` and working directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add "**init**.py" file to the scripts folder,
It's will turn the folder to python package.

and than try

```
from scripts.utils import *
```

Comment: its /__init__/.py not init.py